# Mouse click on VIM tab to create new window

Tags: vimrc

In VIM when I execute `set mouse=a`, then I can use mouse to navigate. That's good. And when I need a new window for editing, I can double click on a tab. VIM will open an empty window for me.

However, I have an annoying problem. I found that when I click on a tab and move the mouse (usually, the move is not on purpose. Accidentally.), it will also create a new window. This annoys me so much such that I cannot browser every tab quickly (should be very careful to click on tab).

Does anyone also have this issue and know how to disable the feature (or bug?) of DRAG to open a new window.

THe OS is Linux running KDE Plasma with konsole terminal application.

Comment: Is this with the mouse on the terminal? Which O.S. and platform?

Comment: On Linux. I run KDE desktop and run VIM via the terminal 'konsole'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround to quickly close accidentally creating new tab by adding right click to close it though I don't like this workaround.

```
nnoremap <RightMouse> :tabclose<CR>
```

---

Finally, I found this is related to the problem of terminal application (KDE konsole). After I switch to other terminal application, simple terminal, the problem is gone.